# Certificates change from Symantec to DigiCert

Tags: certificates

An SAP to Salesforce integration via a REST API uses a certificate provided by Salesforce/DigiCert.

Now that certificate is about to expire and we need to provide them with a new cert. The problem is – I can’t find the site to download the new cert.

[Here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000317640&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) is the location where we downloaded the last certificate - (at the very bottom of the page, it has an attachment that contains the certs).

Can you point us to where we can find the current certificates?

Comment: The new certs are downloadable from the article you're referencing. There's also a link in section 6 of the article if the download link at the bottom doesn't work.